# Start camera for capturing picture and store image after captureing it in gellary on button click

Tags: android, android-camera, image-gallery

I am working on android application. I have an Activity in which there is two button first one for selecting image from gallary. i have applied function on it. i have one more button capture image . i want to work on it .but don't know how to start camera .I want that when i click button capture image it should start camera for capture image.and there should be option to cancel if don't want to take picture. after pressing cancel camera should cancel.
if i captures image it should it should show in Image View and automatically store in SD card .how should i proceed.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html. Everything you need to know about  starting a camera. Go through the link.

```
 private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) ); 
  startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

 get uri
 private File getTempFile(Context context){

  return new File(path, "/tourpath/yourfilename.jpg");
}


 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch(requestCode){
      case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:   
          try {
           Bitmap captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
          iv.setImageBitmap(captureBmp);//show in imageview
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
       }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```